# How to use ITF barcode for wallet passes?

Tags: ios, applepay, wallet

Apple's documentation for passes sais

```
For the barcode dictionary, you can use only the following values: 
PKBarcodeFormatQR, PKBarcodeFormatPDF417, or PKBarcodeFormatAztec. 
For dictionaries in the barcodes array, you may also use 
PKBarcodeFormatCode128.
```

Is it somehow possible to use ITF barcodes with passes? Asking specifically for storeCard type and without possibility to use logo, icon or strip image.

Comment: Sorry, these are the only ones Apple support at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The only formats available are PKBarcodeFormatQR, PKBarcodeFormatPDF417, PKBarcodeFormatAztec, and PKBarcodeFormatCode128 of which the PKBarcodeFormatCode128 is not compatible with watchOS.

**To answer your question:** No, Apple currently doesn't support ITF barcodes.